# Is there any way to allow/restrict users to view the Azure Logic App and Logic App Workflow

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

Is there any way to allow/restrict users to view the Azure Logic App and Logic App Workflow

I created a Azure Logic App and workflows to create Azure Devops Repository using REST API Method. On a security perspective, how to allow / restrict users to view the Logic App Designer (workflow). Or is there any way we can hide the values which are provided by me and other users cant view it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to allow/restrict users to view the Azure Logic App and Logic App Workflow

AFAIK, there is no such permission is in place which will restrict the users to view the workflow, instead you can grant `Logic App Standard Reader (Preview)`  RBAC role for read only access. As per the new [RBAC](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/announcement-azure-logic-apps-standard-rbac-roles-in-public/ba-p/3906600) roles announced for logic app standard standard, you can provide granular access to the users according to your requirement.

[image]

> is there any way we can hide the values which are provided by me and other users cant view it.

Yes, you can hide the input and output values by enabling secure inputs and outputs in the settings of your required action as below.

[image]

Then, you will get the output as below

[image]

Comment: Hi Afrin, Thank you very much for your help