# Is there a way to hide values/parameters in Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I want project id not visible to all, is there a way to hide values/parameters which we want to hide in body of HTTP Trigger in Logic App. Please help.
Also i see default branch not creating under repository, which im manually initializing after repo created. Please suggest as well. Thanks

[image]

Comment: please refer my answer in this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265741/is-there-any-way-to-allow-restrict-users-to-view-the-azure-logic-app-and-logic-a

Comment: Hi Afrin, i have gone through the page which you shared, looks that is output right which we can see after workflow run. But im looking if anyone can open the work flow & those can not see inside parameters section in HTTP body like project id etc. so is there a way to hide/not visible to others, like we can store that project id some where & can call it in body of that HTTP. Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Parameters and refer them in your workflow like below-

[image]

[image]

Or, you can pass the parameters as a payload if you use `When a HTTP request is received` as a trigger.

[image]

[image]

You need to pass the parameter value while invoking.

[image]